# drop down with lookup and contains - google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

We have a sheet 2 that gets imported for sake of argument say we have column A contains a list of first names, column B is their associated age  i.e  A1=John  B1:32

on our first sheet 1 we have column a with a dropdown with Complete Names (first/last) and I want to populate column B with their associated age from sheet2  i.e. A1=John Doe B1=32

This is our data simplified for need...

So basically Sheet1 column B needs to search Sheet2:A for the first name and return the age based on the dropdown value of Sheet1:A

I'm sure its a matter of combining the right vlookup, regexmatch or something else...many thanks up front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Sample Data (Sheet2):

[image: Sample]

#### Formula:

```
=vlookup(regexreplace(A2, " .*", ""), Sheet2!A:B, 2, false)
```

- `regexreplace` above will return the first name (name before the first space). You can also use `regexextract` alternatively.
- `vlookup` will then find that first name that has been returned in `Sheet2!A:A` and return its respective value in `Sheet2!B:B`

#### Output (Sheet1):

[image: output]

Comment: Bingo....Hot Damn....winner winner chicken dinner.....merci beaucoup - worked like a charm